sse4.2 _mm_cmpistrm/_mm_cmpestrm instruction get wrong result
I want to use the following code to compute the intersection of array a and array b:
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
void test(uint16_t *a, uint16_t *b) {
    __m128i v_a = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)a);
    __m128i v_b = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)b);
    __m128i res_v1 = _mm_cmpistrm(v_a, v_b, _SIDD_UWORD_OPS | _SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY | _SIDD_BIT_MASK);
    uint32_t mask_a = _mm_extract_epi32(res_v1, 0);
    __m128i res_v2 = _mm_cmpistrm(v_b, v_a, _SIDD_UWORD_OPS | _SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY | _SIDD_BIT_MASK);
    uint32_t mask_b = _mm_extract_epi32(res_v2, 0);
    printf("match a:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (mask_a & (1 << (7 - i))) {
            printf(" %d", a[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    printf("match b:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (mask_b & (1 << (7 - i))) {
            printf(" %d", b[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
int main() {
    uint16_t a[] = {13, 18, 19, 24, 97, 104, 456, 1024};
    uint16_t b[] = {11, 17, 18, 19, 24, 58, 104, 456};
    test(a, b);
}

I expected the output is:
match a: 18 19 24 104 456
match b: 18 19 24 104 456

however actually the result is:
match a: 13 18 24 97 104
match b: 17 18 24 58 104

It seems like _mm_cmpistrm instruction give me wrong result!
Is there any mistake in my code, or there are bugs in Intel CPU?
If I made mistakes, how can I fix it?

That code uses the masks "in reverse" in two different ways:

it implicitly takes the bit-reverse of the mask.
it interprets the mask resulting from _mm_cmpistrm(v_a, v_b, ... as indicating the elements from a that are also in b, but that mask indicates elements from b that are also in a.

With this code,
void test(uint16_t *a, uint16_t *b) {
    __m128i v_a = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)a);
    __m128i v_b = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)b);
    __m128i res_v1 = _mm_cmpistrm(v_a, v_b, _SIDD_UWORD_OPS | _SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY | _SIDD_BIT_MASK);
    uint32_t mask_b = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(res_v1);
    __m128i res_v2 = _mm_cmpistrm(v_b, v_a, _SIDD_UWORD_OPS | _SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY | _SIDD_BIT_MASK);
    uint32_t mask_a = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(res_v2);
    printf("match b:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (mask_b & (1 << i)) {
            printf(" %d", b[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    printf("match a:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (mask_a & (1 << i)) {
            printf(" %d", a[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

I get the output:
match b: 18 19 24 104 456
match a: 18 19 24 104 456


Thanks, your answer really fixed the issue! Thank you very much!
